# How to hide column of webgrid I am able to hide headder of the webgrid using below code hides the data but column still comes in the UI as blank

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I hide a column of webgrid? I am able to hide header of the webgrid. Using the code below hides the data but column still appears in the UI as blank. Below is my code to hide the column but it doesn't work:

```csharp
@grid.GetHtml(
  htmlAttributes: new { @id = "WebGrid", @class = "Grid" },
  columns: webGrid.Columns(  
    grid.Column("Sr.No.", format: item => rowVal = rowVal + 1),
    grid.Column(null, null, format: @<input type="hidden" name="IDHidden" value="@item.ID" />)
  )
)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow please always include what exactly does not work - what is the expected output. It changes a lot tothe question and guessing can lead to unrelevant answers.

Comment: WebGrid only shows the columns you provide it. If you don't want a column shown, don't provide information for that column.

Comment: I have created my own id which i dont want to show the user so how can i do this in mvc web grid.